# Understanding how libzip works

Tags: linux, archive, libzip

I have started working with the libzip library today. But I do not understand the principle how libzip works.

My focus is on zipping a directory with all the files and dirs within
 into a zip-file.

Therefore, I started with `zip_open()`, then I read the directory
 contents and add all the dirs with `zip_dir_add()` to the archive.
 After that, I closed the zip-file with `zip_close()`. Everything was
 fine. The next step should be to add all the files to the archive with
 `zip_file_add()`. But it doesn't work. The last step closing the file
 fails.

OK, I forgot to create a zip_source to get this done. I added a
 statement a line before to get this source (`zip_source_file()`). But
 still it doesn't work.

What is wrong in my thinking? Do I have to `fopen()` and `fclose()` the file on the filesystem also?

And what is the difference between zip_source_file() and zip_source_filep()?

Comment: zip_close would be last, after adding all files, structure etc.  The zip itself is a file with a pointer, on closing said pointer, you will no longer be able to write to the pointer, and so you cannot add files after closing.

Comment: OK, I know. Perhaps I didn't write it. But I did it first step: zip_open(), zip_dir_add(), zip_close(). Next step was zip_open(), zip_dir_add(), zip_source_file(), zip_file_add(), zip_close(). But one closing I get a error = -1.

Comment: Hey @tria1312 did you find any solution? i have a similar problem.

Comment: Posting the source code would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to fopen() and fclose() the file on the filesystem also?

No, you can just use `zip_source_file()`.

From your comments I think you have the right general idea, but there is probably some detail that is making it fail. Make sure you perform all the [error checking the documentation suggests](https://libzip.org/documentation/libzip.html#ERROR_HANDLING) after each libzip call so you can get more information about what is causing it to fail.

You could also compare your code with https://gist.github.com/clalancette/bb5069a09c609e2d33c9858fcc6e170e